# If the generating function summation and zeta regularized sum of a divergent series exist, do they always coincide?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, dirichlet-series, divergent-series

One could assign a value to [divergent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) by means of several summation methods. One summation method we could consider is the generating function method. Let's sum, for example, the fibonacci series  by means of this method. We consider the generating function of the fibonacci series: $$ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n} x^{n},  $$ in which the $n$'th Fibonacci number is defined as: $f_{n} = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2} $ and $f_{0} = 0 $ and $f_{1} = 1$. In the following wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) it is explained (amongst many other things) that it is possible to find a closed-form for $g$: $$g(x) = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2} . $$ Therefore, we could state that the divergent series summation by means of the generating function summation method $G$ amounts to taking the following limit: $$ G \Big{(} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n} \Big{)} = \lim_{x \to 1} g(x) = -1 .  $$
We could, also try to assign a value to the sum of all Fibonacci numbers by means of zeta function regularisation. A closed form of the function $$ z(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}^{-x} $$ can be found in equation $(5)$ of the following [paper](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/39-5/navas.pdf) by Navas. (Who mistakenly asserts that he is finding the analytic continuation of the Fibonacci Dirichlet series. He is actually doing zeta function regularization of the Fibonacci series. The two methods are confused quite often, though.) He finds that $$ z(x) = 5^{x/2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-x}{k} \frac{1}{\phi^{x+2k} + (-1)^{k+1} } . $$ The zeta regularized sum $R$ of the Fibonacci series is therefore $$ R \Big{(} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n} \Big{)} = \lim_{x \to -1} z(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \Big{(} \frac{1}{\phi^{-1} -1} + \frac{1}{\phi + 1} \Big{)} = -1 .$$ We have thus found that the generating function summation and the zeta regularized sum of the Fibonacci series coincide (define $F := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n} )$ : $$ G(F) = -1 = R(F) .$$
This does not always happen, though. If we define the sum of natural numbers $ N = \sum_{n =1}^{\infty} n $, then $G (N) $ does not exist. This is because the corresponding generating function amounts to $$ p(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n} = \frac{1}{ (1-x)^{2} } , $$ for which $\lim_{x \to 1 } p(x) $ does not exist. The zeta regularized sum *does* exist, however. We have the notorious equation $R(N) = - \frac{1}{12} $ (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_...) page).

Question **(1)** is now: Do the $G$ and $R$ summation methods of a divergent series always coincide, if both methods lead to a finite number that can be assigned to the divergent series at hand?

Question **(2)**: Is there a closed form of the *actual* analytic continuation of the Fibonacci dirichlet series $ d(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ f_{n} }{ n^{x} } $ ?

**Bonus** question: are there any references for collections of generating function expansion, zeta function analytic continuations and analytic continuations of dirichlet series? For the first group of functions there is the book Generatingfunctionology by Wilf, but I can't find any big overview papers/books/articles on the last two groups of functions.

Comment: Cross-posted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906980/if-the-generating-function-summation-and-zeta-regularized-sum-of-a-divergent-exi

Comment: A quibble: The way the first example is worded may give a misleading impression, blurring "taking a limit" with "evaluation of meromorphic continuation at a point". If the meromorphic continuation has the desired point at the edge of the circle of convergence, then a non-tangential limit should give the same outcome, yes, but the idea is not restricted to that case...

Comment: Duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19410/do-abel-summation-and-zeta-summation-always-coincide

Comment: @DavidSpeyer No, I don't think it's a duplicate. I think we have a different idea of what zeta summation is. You are actually doing summation by means of the analytic continuation of the corresponding dirichlet series. Therefore, you take the limit $ \lim_{x \to 0 } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n^{x}} $. However, I take the limit $\lim_{x \to -1 } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} { {a_{n}}^{-x}} $ . The methods are confused quite often with one another, though.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Related, but not the same.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Although perhaps similar arguments given in answers to your question can be used to answer mine?

Comment: Regarding your question about the Fibonacci Dirichlet series, can't you just take $\frac{1}{\Gamma\left( x \right)} \int_0^{\infty} g(e^{-t}) t^{x} \frac{dt}{t}$ where $g$ is the function you defined?

Comment: @darkl Maybe, could you elaborate?

Comment: The idea is that the Mellin transform of $e^{-kt}$ is $\Gamma\left( x \right)\frac{1}{k^x}$ (by the definition of the Gamma function and by changing variable). So if you apply the Mellin transform to $g(x)$ you get $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Gamma\left( x \right) \frac{f_k}{k^x}$. See also [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Zeta_Function) for a similar argument for the Zeta function.

Comment: @darkl Hmm alright. I don't completely understand how this works yet, but if you can show it does indeed amount to the appropriate series and that the limit $x \to 0$ exists and is finite, then I suppose it could be a fitting method.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the example of the Riemann zeta function. One then considers the generating function of $f(y) = \sum_{n \geq 1} y^{n} $, which amounts to $\frac{y}{1-y} $, after which you plug in $y=e^{-x}$ to obtain $f(e^{-x}) = \frac{1}{e^{x}-1}$, right? Hence the choice of $f$ in the example.

Comment: @Max Muller yeah, exactly. You should be able to express your Fibonacci Dirichlet series as a linear combination of geometric Dirichlet series, perhaps these are more studied in the literature?

Comment: @MaxMuller You need to clarify the analyticity-meromorphicity conditions you are assuming for your functions.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding question number 2, you can write $f_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \phi^k - \left(1-\phi\right)^k \right)$, where $\phi^2 = \phi + 1$, $\phi > 0$. Hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{f_k}{k^s} = \frac{1}{\sqrt5} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\phi^k - \left(1-\phi\right)^k}{k^s}$$
By the definition of the [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{f_k}{k^s} = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}\mathrm{Li}_s\left( \phi \right) - \frac{1}{\sqrt5}\mathrm{Li}_s\left( 1-\phi \right)$$

Comment: Thank you. If we do the elementary algebra, we find this amounts to $-1$ as well, when $s=0$.