# Resources for divergent / asymptotic series

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

*This series is divergent; therefore, we may be able to do something with it.* -- Oliver Heaviside

[Edit (1/14/21) from the answer by Count Iblis to a recent MO-Q on math vids: An enthusiastic intro is that to the set of lectures by Carl Bender "[Perturbation and Asymptotic Series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL43B1963F261E6E47)." ]

Other than the usual references given in Wikipedia and Mathworld, which resources have you found helpful as intros to the topic and for advanced exploration?

I'll prime the pump with

1. "[Divergent series:taming the tails](https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/berry482.pdf)" by M. V. Berry and C. J. Howls (cf. also refs in this [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227642/investigation-of-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-fracxkn-gammakn1/227660#227660))
2. Sporadic examples in Heaviside's publications, see [Heaviside's Operational Calculus](https://www.google.com/amp/s/deadreckonings.com/2007/12/07/heavisides-operator-calculus/amp/), a post by Ron Doerfler.
3. [A Singular Mathematical Promenade](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.06373) by Etienne Guys
4. [Sum Divergent Series](https://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/07/28/sum-divergent-series-i/) by the user mnoonan, a series of posts at The Everything Seminar
5. "[Euler's constant:
   Euler's work and modern developments](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1856)" by Jeffrey Lagarias
6. "[Uniform asymptotic methods for integrals](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001935771300061X)" by Nico Temme
7. "[On the Specialness of Special Functions (The Nonrandom Effusions of the Divine Mathematician)](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/2629/)" by
   Robert W. Batterman

For one example of the importance of such series, see the relation between the Harer-Zagier formula and the asymptotic expansion of the digamma function in Chapter 5 "The Euler characteristic of the moduli space of curves" of the course notes "[Mathematical ideas and notions of quantum field theory](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Elinlin/2017Spring_290/ETI.pdf)" by Etingof.

Comment: Hardy's book *Divergent Series*? Or is that one of the usual references?

Comment: @Robert Furber, yep, under asymptotic series in Wiki. (Divergent Series has been google hijacked by Hollywood). Years ago when I had an excellent home library, I saved some early paper by Hardy in which he expressed what I have called The Hardy Heuristic. Goes something like: Apply two operations consecutively in one order then reverse the order. If one order is convergent and the other divergent, you have a summation method. If you can find that ref, would be a good one. Lost my library and have no access to a good University lib myself.

Comment: Écalle, Malgrange and Ramis work on Gevrey series may be also a good track.

Comment: I would add the tauberian theory bible of J Korevaar; there is also a survey of complex Tauberian theory by the author here (pdf linked) http://www.jointmathematicsmeetings.org/bull/2002-39-04/S0273-0979-02-00951-5/S0273-0979-02-00951-5.pdf

Comment: @Conrad, that's fitting. I found the Temme ref (or was reminded again of him) just last night in "Early work of N.G. (Dick) de Bruijn in analysis and
some of my own" by Korevaar.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier, I found "Fonctions multisommables" by Malgrange and Ramis (in which Watson's "A theory of asymptotic series" is reffed). Which papers by E, M, and R would be a good intro to their work?

Comment: As was expressed the tauberian theorems are very important. On the side of divergent series I know from an informative point of view Kolmogorov studied divergent series (see *History* from the Wikipedia *Carleson's theorem*). Myself attempt of learning is to search and study concise articles that I can understand about divergent series, for example R. P. Agnew, *A Slowly Divergent Series*, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 54, No. 5 (May, 1947) pp. 273-274, or T. S. Nanjundiah, *Extensions of Olivier's Theorem*, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 76, No. 6 (Jul, 1969) pp. 666-667.

Comment: I can read these for free with my account of JSTOR.

Comment: Worth panning, but no time for me at the moment: "How Euler Did It" , an online MAA column, written by Ed Sandifer from 2003 to 2010. These are archived at  http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/.

Comment: Again, back to the source--the mathemage, Euler--in "Euler and his work on infinite series" by Varadarajan (https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2007-44-04/S0273-0979-07-01175-5/S0273-0979-07-01175-5.pdf). See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19201/summation-methods-for-divergent-series and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45811/use-of-everywhere-divergent-generating-functions/45868#45868.

Comment: And  "Euler's 1760 paper on divergent series" by Barbeau and Leah     https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086076900306

Comment: "Convergence from Divergence" by Costin and Dunne https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09687

Comment: Also a translation by Aycock of Euler's "On divergent series" https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.02841

Comment: "Transseries for beginners" by G. A. Edgar https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.4877

Comment: On the iconic divergent power series with $a_n = n!$, see refs in https://oeis.org/A003319 and the blog posts https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/the-answer-to-the-puzzle/, https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/04/the-categorical-exponential-formula/, and https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2014/12/14/the-hirzebruch-criterion-fo-the-todd-class/.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258525/how-do-i-solve-this-displaystyle-f-ef-1 and discussion on formal inversion (multiplicative and compositional) of and composition with divergent series.

Comment: See also the book Continued Fractions by Jones and Thron.

Comment: "On Numbers, Germs, and Transseries" by Aschenbrenner, van den Dries, van der Hoeven https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06936 and "Asymptotics and Borel Summability" by Costin

Comment: "On the Specialness of Special Functions (The Nonrandom Effusions of the Divine Mathematician)" by Batterman and the refs therein.

Comment: "Differential Equations: A Dynamical Systems Approach" by Hubbard and West. See the Appendix: Asymptotic Development.

Comment: Another book by Balser not mentioned in Wikipedia: "Formal Power Series and Linear Systems of Meromorphic Differential Equations."  Wikipedia and MathWorld links are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Summability_methods, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Asymptotic_analysis, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AsymptoticSeries.html, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergentSeries.html

Comment: Fairly comprehensive intro: Quantum Field Theory II: Quantum Electrodynamics by Zeidler

Comment: "Polynomial expansions of Analytic Functions" by Boas and Buck

Comment: "From Resurgence to BPS States" by Marino https://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/stringsmirrors/2019/2_M_Marino.pdf

Comment: Despite the exhortations against divergent series / formal power series by Abel, since at least Laplace, such series have found important applications in physics. See, e.g., "Divergent series: past, present, future . . . " by Christiane Rousseau (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5712.pdf).

Comment: See also applications in Operational Calculus (2nd ed.) by Bremmer and van der Pol.

Comment: Informal intro with some history: the 2023 video by Sir Michael Berry - Divergent Series: From Thomas Bayes's Bewilderment to Today's Resurgence (https://youtu.be/73CLvdrdKuU?si=FVt1Lq1-dCl1Fo9E)

Comment: 'Summability, Tauberian theorems, and Fourier series' a blog post at https://www.victorchen.org/2019/10/21/summability-tauberian-fourier-series/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as on-line-available things go, I've attempted to modernize some arguments and give examples of asymptotics of integrals (both Watson's Lemma and easy Laplace/saddle-point examples), as well as asymptotics for ordinary differential equations, both regular and certain irregular singular points. On-line, as well as a chapter in my Cambridge Univ Press book of 2018 ([http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/current_version.pdf](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/current_version.pdf)). For earlier, separate treatments, see [http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2019-20/05e_asymptotics_of_integrals.pdf](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/mfms/notes_2019-20/05e_asymptotics_of_integrals.pdf), [http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/11b_reg_sing_pt.pdf](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/11b_reg_sing_pt.pdf), and [http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/11c_irreg_sing_pt.pdf](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/11c_irreg_sing_pt.pdf). Those notes (and the book, on-line or not) have substantial bibliographic/historical references.

Comment: Nice lists of references. I'm wondering if you could contribute to the somewhat related MO-Q https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397238/renormalization-in-physics-vs-dynamical-systems.

Comment: @TomCopeland, I'll take a look... :)

Comment: @TomCopeland, although rigorous notions of "asymptotic expansion" might put that other question and its answers into a broader context, it doesn't seem that that's the main issue in that question.