# Generalized limits

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, divergent-series

*Cross-posted [from Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298993/generalized-limits).*

The linked question explores the concept of a "generalized limit" that assigns values to sequences which diverge in the Cauchy sense. It asks the following question:

> Does there exist an "explicitly definable" generalized limit
>   $\operatorname{Lim} : X^\mathbb{N} \rightharpoonup X$ that is stronger
>   than the *linear and stable closure* of the Cauchy limit?

I'd be curious to know what such a $\operatorname{Lim}$ might be.

As Gerald pointed out, the concept of an [almost convergent sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence) is relevant.

Comment: What does it mean for a generalised limit to be 'stronger' than something?

Comment: @LSpice $\operatorname{Lim}_1$ is stronger than $\operatorname{Lim}_2$ iff $\operatorname{Lim}_2 \subseteq \operatorname{Lim}_1$.

Comment: Ah, so the $\rightharpoonup$ notation indicates a partial function?

Comment: @LSpice That's right.

Comment: It might be of interest to you that there is a vast literature on the topic of generalized limits going back at least to Hardy's "Divergent series".  The most recent one that I know of  is "Classical and modern methods in summability"  by J. Boos which contains references to earlier work.  There seems to be a cultural divide between those who discuss convergence of sequences, respectively summability of series but they are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: What is $X$? And what does *stable* mean?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not what generalization you are looking for, because it extends the range of possible values of generalized limits beyond the complex numbers but it can possibly be interesting to you (and any generalized limit has a regularized part which may be of interest).

The approach is based on evaluating the integral of the derivative of the function at a point in the following way:

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to u^+}f(x)=f(a)+\int_u^a f'(x)dx$$

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to u^-}f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^u f'(x)dx$$

After we made an association between the limit and the corresponding integral, all we need to do is to ascribe a value to the divergent integral.

The simplest method is to sum up the integral using Cesaro summation, this will give us the average value of the function as it approaches the point of interest.

But in cases when the integral grows to infinity Cesaro summation won't work.

So, in this case we would want to express the infinitely-large divergent integrals through other divergent integrals, and also hopefully find the regularized values of them.

For instance, it is quite natural that if we assign some value to the integral $\int_0^\infty dx$ then $\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to\infty} x$ would be that same value and $\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to\infty} 2x$ would be twice that much.

That said I refer you to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651) regarding divergent integrals.

To summarize that approach, it turned out that employing some parallels in fourier analysis and the theory of hyperfunctions, it is possible to write down in closed form a large range of generalized limits.

if we define

$$\tau=\int_0^\infty dx=\pi\delta(0)$$

$$\omega_+=\tau+1/2$$

and

$$\omega_-=\tau-1/2$$

then there is a lot of limits that can be described in these terms.

For instance,

$$\omega_-^n=\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to\infty}B_n(x)$$

$$\omega_+^n=\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to\infty}B_n(x+1)$$

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to\infty}x^n=0^n+i^{n-1}\pi n\delta^{(n-1)}(0)=\frac{\omega _+^{n+1}-\omega _-^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac1{x^n}=0^n+\frac{i^{n-1}\pi\delta^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}=\frac{\omega _+^{n+1}-\omega _-^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}3=\int_0^\infty x^2dx=\tau^3 +\frac\tau{4}=\pi \delta''(0)$$

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}2=\int_0^{\infty } x \, dx = \frac{\tau ^2}{2}+\frac{1}{24} = i\pi\delta'(0)$$

It is also possible to evaluate the function's poles using generalized limits. The limits would be polynomials of $\tau$ of the same order as the function's pole, with Cauchy's principle value representing the regularized part.

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to0^\pm}\Gamma(0)=-\gamma\pm\tau$$

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to{-1}^\pm}\Gamma(x)=\gamma-1\mp\tau$$

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to{-2}^\pm}\Gamma(x)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{\gamma }{2}\pm\frac\tau 2$$

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to{-3}^\pm}\Gamma(x)=\frac{\gamma }{6}-\frac{11}{36}\mp\frac\tau 6$$

$$\operatorname{gen}\lim_{x\to1^\pm}\zeta(x)=\gamma\pm\tau$$

[Here is a table](https://extended.fandom.com/wiki/Extended_Wiki#Some_extended_numbers) with some other values.

Comment: One has to be very conservative extending the range of possible limits beyond the complex numbers, or else you could do something like taking the codomain to be the quotient of $X^{\mathbb N}$ by the ideal of sequences tending to $0$.  (Of course you haven't done this, but what I mean is that it might be easy to sneak up accidentally on doing this by innocent-seeming steps.)

Comment: @LSpice can you please provide an example of what your concern can lead to.

Comment: What I meant is that the natural projection $X^{\mathbb N} \to X^{\mathbb N}/c_0(X)$ is a reasonable, if not very interesting, kind of "generalised limit with generalised values", and, via the inclusion of constant sequences $X \hookrightarrow X^{\mathbb N}$, agrees with the usual limit on convergent sequences; but it seems likely it's not what @user76284 had in mind.  (It's also not what you said!  I just meant that some care needs to be taken when extending the admissible values of the limit.)

Comment: @LSpice as an algebraist, what do you think about algebraic properties of the linked system? I posted a question about this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390772/what-are-the-algebraic-properties-of-this-numerical-system

Comment: With all due respect, I think that advertising about it in questions to which it does not seem directly related doesn't belong here; but the voting on [your answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651) shows that that might be a minority opinion.

Comment: @LSpice as you can see it directly mentions the generalized limits. It was before this question posted. I do not know what topic can be related closer if we talk about limits of divergent series.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition 2 adds nothing.  Given any $\text{Lim}$ you can write it as $\lim \circ f$ where $f$ maps each sequence $\mathbf x$ to the constant sequence with value $\text{Lim}(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: But is there an explicit such $f$?

Comment: I guess $f$ is explicit exactly when $\text{Lim}$ was already explicit.

Comment: Maybe consult the material on Banach limits, in particular connect your ideas to the notion "almost convergent" found there.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit

Comment: To give an idea of what I meant by an "explicit" sequence transformation, one example is the Cesàro transformation described in the second half of the original question.

Comment: Good point about Banach limits. If I understand correctly, though, these are non-constructive, right?

Comment: @user76284, re: [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345164/generalized-limits#comment863475_345166), while it is a good idea to edit your question, it is not generally considered polite to do so in a way that completely invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @LSpice The edit does not invalidate this answer. The original question already asked for an explicit transformation. I just edited it to make it less confusing.