# Uses of Divergent Series and their summation-values in mathematics?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, divergent-series, big-list

This question was posed originally on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/uses-of-divergent-series-and-their-summation-values-in-mathematics), I put it here because I didn't receive the answer(s) I wished to see.

Dear MO-Community,

When I was trying to find closed-form representations for odd zeta-values, I used 
$$ \Gamma(z) = \frac{e^{-\gamma \cdot z}}{z} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( 1 + \frac{z}{n} \Big)^{-1} e^{\frac{z}{n}} $$ 
and rearranged it to 
$$ \frac{\Gamma(z)}{e^{-\gamma \cdot z}} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( 1 + \frac{z}{n} \Big)^{-1} e^{z/n}. $$
As we know that $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{z/n} = e^{z + z/2 + z/3 + \cdots + z/n} = e^{\zeta(1) z},$$ 
we can state that 
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( 1 + \frac{z}{n} \Big) = \frac{e^{z(\zeta(1) - \gamma)}}{z\Gamma(z)} \tag 1$$
I then stumbled upon the Wikipedia page of [Ramanujan Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) (see the bottom of the page), which I used to set $\zeta(1) = \gamma$ (which was, admittedly, a rather dangerous move. Remarkably, things went well eventually. Please don't stop reading). The $z^3$ -coefficient of both sides can now be obtained. Consider 
\begin{align*}
(1-ax)(1-bx) &= 1 - (a+b)x + abx^2\\\
&= 1-(a+b)x + (1/2)((a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2))
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}(1-ax)(1-bx)(1-cx) &= 1 - (a + b + c)x\\\
&\qquad + (1/2)\Bigl((a + b + c)^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)\Bigr)x^2\\\
&\qquad -(abc)x^3.
\end{align*}

We can also set 
\begin{align*}
(abc)x^3 &= (1/3)\Bigl((a^3 + b^3 + c^3) - (a + b + c)\Bigr)\\\
&\qquad + (1/2)(a + b + c)^3 -(a + b + c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2).
\end{align*}
It can be proved by induction that the x^3 term of $(1-ax)(1-bx)\cdots(1-nx)$ is equal to 
$$\begin{array} {lll}
\phantom+ (1/3)  \Bigl((a^3 + b^3 + c^3 +\cdots + n^3) - (a + b + c + \cdots + n)^3\Big) \\ 
+ (1/2)\Big((a + b + c + \cdots + n)^3 \\
\qquad\qquad -(a + b + c + \cdots + n)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \cdots + n^2)\Big).
\end{array} \tag 2 $$
On the right side of equation (1), the $z^3$-term can be found by looking at the $z^3$ term of the Taylor expansion series of $1/(z \Gamma(z))$, which is $(1/3)\zeta(3) + (1/2)\zeta(2) + (1/6)\gamma^3$. We then use (2) to obtain the equality
$$ (1/6)\gamma^3 - (1/2)\gamma \pi^2 - (1/6) \psi^{(2)}(1) = 1/3)\zeta(3) + (1/2)\zeta(2) + (1/6)\gamma^3$$ 
to find that 
$$\zeta(3) = - (1/2) \psi^{(2)} (1),\tag 3$$ 
which is a true result that has been 
[known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant) (*known* should be a hyperlink but it isn't for some reason) for quite a long time. The important thing here is that I used $\zeta(1) = \gamma$, which isn't really true. Ramanujan assigned a summation value to the harmonic series (again, see Ramanujan Summation), and apparently it can be used to verify results and perhaps to prove other conjectures/solve problems.

> My first question is: Is this a legitimate way to prove (3) ?

Generalizing this question:

> When and how are divergent series and their summation values used in mathematics?
>   What are the 'rules' when dealing with summed divergent series and using them to (try to) find new results?

Thanks,

Max

As I suspect someone (I was thinking of Qiaochu Yuan himself) will add this too, I will add this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3204/does-any-method-of-summing-divergent-series-work-on-the-harmonic-series) for him/her, as it is somewhat related.

Comment: +1 for "please don't stop reading". (I will introduce it in the middle of the next paper)

Comment: Sorry, which is equation (2) ? would you add the eqation numbers? Also, what is $\psi^(2)$?

Comment: @ Pietro Majer: Equation (2) is the x^3 term of (1-ax)(1-bx)...(1-nx). The (2) is hidden behind/next to the "related questions".

Comment: For the second question, see the Polygamma function article on Wikipedia.

Comment: Max, do you have enough background to read a beginning text on complex analysis? Maybe somebody can suggest one that gets quickly to product and series developments. The basic example of value assignment for divergent series is not an assignment at all, it is simply reporting the value of  analytic continuation of the function at a point outside the open disk of guaranteed convergence. Other meanings have sometimes occurred, but your idea of finding a divergent series or product and giving the most pleasing value is, well, not good.

Comment: Adding to Will's comment: there is a very readable book of Konrad Knopp on series; chap XII on complex series, chap XIII specifically on divergent series. In its (original) german version it can be downloaded as scanned pdf from digicener Göttingen. There is also an english translation available, however unfortunately I don't know whether this is also online.

Comment: @ Pietro Majer: by the way, I'm honored that you may use my words in your next paper. @ Will Jagy: I understand your concerns. I shouldn't just pick a value for $\zeta(1)$ because it gives a correct result. I just thought it was a remarkable coincidence that the result was correct when I used the the summation value of the divergent series in question, and I was wondering if a good explanation of this exists. 

Comment: @ Gottfried Helms: thank you for the suggestion, I found the book "Theory and application of infinite series" by Konrad Knopp on amazon. Chapter XII is devoted to series with complex terms and chapter XIII is on divergent series, so perhaps the book has expanded after you read it or the english version is different ;). 

Comment: Max, there is another venerable topic using divergent series, that is "asymptotic series" or "asymptotic expansions." I have a Dover reprint, "Asymptotic Expansions" by A. Erdelyi. It may be easier to approach than the Knopp book(s), as it emphasizes real entries and real coefficients. The book is 1956, surely there are more recent introductions to asymptotic expansions.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, Will. I will certainly take a look at a book on the subject you mentioned.

Comment: This may be useful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651

Answer (score 4):

RULES ... don't just use divergent series to get an answer unless there is some additional work to show it is meaningful.  Indeed, don't even use rearrangement of conditionally convergent series and expect to get something meaningful (again) unless there is some additional work.

AN EXAMPLE ... **Fourier series** sometimes diverge, but converge when summed (C,1).  There are theorems explaining conditions when the (C,1) sum of a Fourier series for a function actually converges to that function.

Comment: Gerald Edgar: thanks for the answer. Do you have any ideas on how to show that $\zeta(1)=\gamma$, and therefore can be used in this context? 

Comment: Well, not to show that $\zeta(1)=\gamma$, but I am interested in the additional work you mentioned to make such equalities meaningful and useful?

Comment: The best source is Hardy's book, DIVERGENT SERIES.  The simplest of the "additional work" results are known as "Tauberian theorems".


Comment: @MaxMuller $\zeta(1)=\gamma$ from Ramanujan's method: $$\zeta(1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\int_1^n\frac1xdx=\gamma$$

Answer (score 4):

It seems likely to me that your derivation can be modified to just involve convergent series and products, but I have not tried it.

There is however a well-known easy derivation of your identity
$\zeta(3) = - (1/2) \psi^{(2)} (1)$ from the product formula, which is quite close to what you are doing. Note that $\psi=\Gamma'/\Gamma$. Take the logarithmic derivative of the product formula. Then the product becomes a series:
$$\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(z)=-\gamma-\frac 1z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac 1n-\frac 1{z+n}\right)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac 1n-\frac 1{z+n-1}\right). $$
Now just differentiate twice and put $z=1$. All series and products involved converge nice enough so that termwise differentiation is justified.

Answer (score 2):

Without claiming to check your algebra, you appear to be engaging in [zeta function regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization).

Comment: @ Steve Huntsman: thanks for the answer, I haven't read all the info on the link yet but I will do so tomorrow. (It's getting late).

Comment: the article mentions that regularized sums are used to obtain results for conditionally convergent sums, so I think we could count that as an application of summed divergent series... +1.