# Square root of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, quantum-mechanics

I am currently working on the understanding of the stochastic nature of the Schroedinger equation. This has a notable history dating back to Nelson's works and relative criticisms. But one can take a different path and, starting from a random walk process with probability

\begin{equation}
   P(k;N) = \binom{N}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^N,
\end{equation}

one can assume the existence of a "square root" of this process with a complex amplitude

\begin{equation}
   A(k;N) = \binom{N}{k}^\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{N/2}e^{i\phi(k,N)}
\end{equation}

such that $P(k;N)=|A(k;N)|^2$ and $\phi(k,N)$ are some phases exactly determined. These are quantum amplitudes. Is this anything making sense? Does any literature exist about?

Comment: In the classical case, $P(k; N)$ is the probability at time $N$ that the walker is at position $k - (N - k)$. I'm assuming that in the quantum case, $A(k; N)$ is meant to be the amplitude at time $N$ for the walker to be at position $k - (N - k)$. This is certainly "something making sense" in that for each time $N$, you've given a quantum state for the walker, so you can calculate the expected value of an observable at any time.

Comment: One question you might ask is whether there's a unitary map that sends the state at time $N$ to the state at time $N + 1$ for all $N$. If there is, you can then ask whether this map is the evolution operator of a quantum random walk that's been studied before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** This mostly debunks an answer posted by the OP and now deleted. As a consequence of this unfortunate deletion, the argument below might be a little difficult to follow.

---

As explained on the [MSE page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101917/square-root-of-a-wiener-process) you are referring to, very basic arguments show that the limits of the sums $S_n$ you write in your "answer" cannot exist.

Consider for example the second version of $S_n$ (the one based on absolute values) in the simplest possible situation, that is, on the interval $[0,1]$ and when $G\equiv1$. Note that the Gaussian random variables $W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1})$ are independent with variances $t_i-t_{i-1}$. Hence, for every $i$,
$$
E((W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1}))^2)=t_i-t_{i-1},
$$
and, for every $i\ne k$,
$$
E(|W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1})|\cdot|W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})|)=c\cdot\sqrt{t_i-t_{i-1}}\cdot\sqrt{t_k-t_{k-1}},
$$
where it happens that $c=2/\pi$ but this is irrelevant. Again in the simplest case, that is, when $t_i=i/n$ for every $i$, this shows that
$$
E(S_n^2)=1+c\cdot(n-1).
$$
Hence, **in contradiction with what you assert**, the sequence $(S_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ diverges in $L^2$.

To sum up, integrals such as 
$$
\int G\cdot|\mathrm dW|\qquad\text{or}\quad\int G\cdot(\mathrm dW)^{\alpha},
$$
whatever their precise definitions would be, cannot exist due to the (ir)regularity properties of the Brownian paths (except, of course, the second one when $\alpha=1$).

Comment: It is not clear to me how do you cope with the case $(dW)^2$ that is note to have a finite limit. I mean $\int_{t_0}^tG(t')(dW(t'))^2=\int_{t_0}^tG(t')dt'$. This is a particular case of $\int G(dW)^\alpha$ and is well defined in stochastic calculus. We can push this further by considering the case with $(dW)^n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\ge 3$ that gives 0 for the Ito ontegral. So, your argument is not always true and I am asking when it is not with $\alpha$ real.

Comment: Are you claiming that Ito integral does not exist?

Comment: Now I understand what is wrong with your argument. The limit must be taken in the rms sense $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\rangle(S_n-S)\langle$. Your upvotes should be removed.


Comment: Sorry, I meant $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle(S_n-S)^2\rangle$.

Comment: You claim $E(|W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1}||W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1}|)\ne 0$ with $i\ne k$ but increments are not correlated. Could you explain this claim improving your answer, please?

Comment: Indeed: increments are independent hence the expectation is the product of the expectations. And $E(|W(t+s)-W(t)|)=\sqrt{2s/\pi}$ for every nonnegative $s$ and $t$.

Comment: So, you get that absolute values of increments are indeed correlated.

Comment: @Jon: In fact, for any $\alpha < 2$, $\sum\vert W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})\vert^\alpha$ converges to infinity (almost surely) as the mesh goes to zero. So it doesn't converge to a finite result in any sense that I can think of. For $\alpha=2$ it converges in the $L^p$ sense ($p < \infty$), and is the quadratic variation. For $\alpha > 2$ it converges to 0. So, Didier is correct for $\alpha < 2$.

Comment: @Jon: And for $\alpha < 2$ it is not clear what is meant by $(dW)^\alpha$ with no absolute value sign, except in the case $\alpha=1$ in which case you recover the Ito integral.

Comment: @George: Thank you for your answer. I considered this as a complex valued process. Do you mean it would make sense $|dW|^\alpha$ with $\alpha<1$?

Comment: @Jon: For $\alpha < 2$ the integral $\int\vert dW\vert^\alpha$ diverges (considered as a limit of Riemann sums). So, no, it would not make sense. If you want to take $(dW)^\alpha$ as a complex-valued process, you have to say which complex power you are taking, as there will several (infinitely many if $\alpha$ is not rational). Otherwise, I can't see how to make sense of the expression.

Comment: @George: You cannot know how much was waiting for this answer. If I had it before I would have avoided to make a fool of myself. About $(dW)^\alpha$ for a complex valued process I was taking "something" multiplied by a Bernoulli process that takes values $1$ and $i$ with probability $1/2$. But I fear that "something" does not exist...

Comment: @George: Put this as an answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85398/a-class-of-ito-integrals , with some better explanation, and I will accept it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Note: my answer refers to an answer posted by the OP and now deleted. As a consequence, my answer is now difficult to understand.

Comment: @Jon: Ok, but I won't have time to answer any questions in detail tonight. I'll add it to the list of questions which I plan to answer when I have time.

Comment: @George: What would be a Riemann sum for the integral $\int|dW|^{\alpha}$? For that matter, what would be the definition of $\int |du|^{\alpha}$ for **any** function $u$? And how is $(dW)^{\alpha}$ even a process, say for $\alpha>2$ since you seem to say this case is easier?

Comment: @Didier: Just improve it. I will keep as accepted of course. Please, do the same also at math.stackexchange and I will accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: *Just improve it*... Is this a joke?

Comment: I mean with respect to the missing part I deleted of course, as you complained about that. I think that now you are not in a good state of mind. 

Comment: @Didier: Of course I can evade your infinity using the regularization technique $\sum_{i=1}^\infty=-1/2$ (see Hardy's book on divergent series or http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3204/does-any-method-of-summing-divergent-series-work-on-the-harmonic-series). In this case, the diverging integral just becomes 0 and E(|W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1})||W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})|)=0 for $i\ne k$, as my intuition would say. The point is that for a mathematician an infinity could be a disgrace but for a theoretical physicist is a moment of happiness...

Comment: Ok, in the preceding comment it is $ \langle|W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1})||W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})|\rangle\ne 0$ of course. The correct argument is given at http://marcofrasca.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/evading-piaus-paradox/. As a theoretical physicist I am very happy but as a mathematician this is somewhat unsatisfactory.