# A class of Ito integrals

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-processes

I am currently working on stochastic processes and I have met a stumbling block in the Ito integral

$$\int_{t_0}^tdt'G(t')[dW(t')]^\alpha$$

with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha>0$. Textbooks result is given for integer $\alpha$ but not in the more general case that could not exist. Of course, also some good references are welcome.

Comment: This question and its answer by yourself are as absurd, mathematically speaking, as on the other page http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82274/square-root-of-a-stochastic-process/86700#86700. Re the question, I would be curious to see **any** "textbooks result" "given for integer $\alpha$" (even for $\alpha=1$, the integral as written above does not make sense).

Comment: Just put the right answer, taking into account the discussion with George. You will see from this that my answer here is obviously correct and does not worth a downvote. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be in a delusional state about the status of *the discussion with George*. // Unsurprisingly, no answer to my request for (at least) one example of the textbooks mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Didier: Sorry Didier but I am not in a delusional state. I have just accepted your answer. I agree with you that there is a problem. What else? Just George declared that $(dW)^\alpha=0$ with $\alpha>2$ and this is what I obtain below. So, why downvote?

I live mathematics like a pleasure and I may be wrong. It occurred to me sometime in my twenty years long career. I just learn from my errors and go ahead.

Of course, you have been helpful and I gave you thanks accepting your answer and deleting wrong statements. Period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be shown that $[dW(t)]^\alpha=0$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha\ge 3$ generalizing the integer case.

Let us consider the stochastic differential equation $dX(t)=[dW(t)]^\alpha$ with $\alpha>0$. We can write the solution in the form $X(t)=X(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t[dW(t)]^\alpha$ with the integral in the Ito sense. Then, we have to evaluate this integral with the sum
\begin{equation}
   S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n[W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})]^\alpha.
\end{equation}
The power of the Brownian process can be evaluated in the following way
\begin{equation}
   [W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})]^\alpha = [(1+W(t_k)+W(t_{k-1}))-1]^\alpha=
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
   (-1)^\alpha\sum_{l_1=0}^\infty\left(\begin{array}{c}
    \alpha \\
    l_1
   \end{array}\right)(-1)^{l_1}(1+W(t_k)+W(t_{k-1}))^{l_1}=
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
   (-1)^\alpha\sum_{l_1=0}^\infty\sum_{l_2=0}^\infty\left(\begin{array}{c}
    \alpha \\
    l_1
   \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
    l_1 \\
    l_2
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{l_1}
[W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})]^{l_2}
\end{equation}
provided $|W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})|<1$. Now, we can use stochastic calculus to remove powers higher than 2 and it is easy to see that
\begin{equation}
    S_n=(-1)^\alpha\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l_1=0}^\infty\left(\begin{array}{c}
    \alpha \\
    l_1
    \end{array}\right)(-1)^{l_1}-
    (-1)^\alpha\sum_{l_1=0}^\infty\left(\begin{array}{c}
    \alpha \\
    l_1
   \end{array}\right)l_1(-1)^{l_1}\sum_{k=1}^n[W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})]+
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
   (-1)^\alpha\sum_{l_1=0}^\infty\left(\begin{array}{c}
    \alpha \\
    l_1
   \end{array}\right)\frac{l_1(l_1-1)}{2}(-1)^{l_1}
   \sum_{k=1}^n[W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})]^2.
\end{equation}
So, we have the required expansion with coefficients
\begin{eqnarray}
    \mu_0&=&\sum_{l_1=0}^\infty\left(\begin{array}{c}
    \alpha \\
    l_1
    \end{array}\right)(-1)^{l_1} \nonumber \\
    \mu_1&=&\sum_{l_1=0}^\infty\left(\begin{array}{c}
    \alpha \\
    l_1
   \end{array}\right)l_1(-1)^{l_1} \nonumber \\
   \mu_2&=&\sum_{l_1=0}^\infty\left(\begin{array}{c}
    \alpha \\
    l_1
   \end{array}\right)\frac{l_1(l_1-1)}{2}(-1)^{l_1}
\end{eqnarray}
Now we see immediately that $\mu_0=\left.(1-x)^\alpha\right|_{x=1}=0$. Besides, we get immediately the result that, for any real $\alpha\ge 3$, we have again $[dW(t)]^\alpha=0$ as in this case the coefficients are all zero when $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are evaluated thorugh Abel summation. Finally, when $0<\alpha<1$ both the coefficients $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are divergent and maybe no meaning can be attached to them (I have in mind summable divergent series here, any suggestion is greatly appreciated).